# Report of oozie jobs

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

How can we get status of Oozie jobs running daily? We have many jobs running in Oozie coordinator and currently we are monitoring through Hue/Oozie browser.

Is there any way we can get a single log file which contains coordinator name/workflow name with date and status? Can we write any program or script to achieve this?

Comment: All the answers are focussed on the Oozie command line; but if you are interested in a **programmatic** way to do it, look at that other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503520/exporting-jobs-listed-in-oozie-web-console/

Answer (score 2):

You use the below command and put it into a script to run it daily/cron.

```
oozie jobs -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -filter status=RUNNING -len 2
oozie jobs -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -filter startCreatedTime=2016-06-28T00:00Z\;endcreatedtime=2016-06-28T10:00Z -len 2
```

Basically you are using oozie's `jobs` api and `-filter` command to get the information about workflow/coordinator/bundle. The `-filter` command supports couple of options to get the data based on `status`/`startCreatedTime`/`name`.

By default, it will bring the workflow record information, if you want to get the coordinator/bindle information. You can use the `-jobtype` parameter and value as `coord/bundle`.

Let me know if you need anything specifically. The oozie doc is little outdated for this feature.

Comment: This returns only jobs which are in running status. I would like to get details of all jobs that ran yesterday night to know whether they are successful or failed.

Comment: I have added the example with `startCreatedTime` parameter. You can also add similarly `endCreatedTime` to restrict the interval.

Answer (score 2):

Command to get status of all running oozie coordinators

```
oozie jobs -jobtype coordinator -filter status=RUNNING -len 1000 -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie
```

Command to get status of all running oozie workflows

```
oozie jobs -filter status=RUNNING -len 1000 -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie
```

Command to get status of all workflows for a specific coordinator ID

```
oozie job -info COORDINATOR_ID_HERE
```

Based on these queries you can write required scripts to get what you want.

Terms explanation:

- `oozie` : Command to initiate oozie
- `job/jobs` : API
- `len`: No. of oozie workflows/coordinators to display
- `-oozie`: Param to specify oozie url
- `-filter` : Param to specify list of filters.

Complete documentation https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_CommandLineTool.html

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me.

```
oozie jobs -oozie http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:11000/oozie -jobtype wf -len 300 | grep 2016-07-01 > OozieJobsStatus_20160701.txt
```

However we need to parse the file.

Comment: Yes. This command will work and do the job, it is just not optimal. You can use the different filter parameters provided by oozie.