# Exporting jobs listed in Oozie Web Console

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Apologies if this question sounds basic, I'm totally new to Hadoop environment.

**What am I looking for?**

In my case, there are jobs scheduled to run everday and *I would want to export the list of failed jobs in an excel sheet each day*.

**How do I view the workflow jobs?**

Currently I use the Oozie web console to view the jobs and I don't have/see an option to export. Also, 
I was not able to find this information from the [Oozie documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Checking_the_Status_of_multiple_Workflow_Jobs).

However, I found that jobs can be listed using commands like

`$ oozie jobs -oozie http://localhost:8080/oozie -localtime -len 2 -fliter status=RUNNING`

**Where am I stuck?**

I want to filter the failed jobs for a given date and **would want to export it as csv/excel data**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Report of oozie jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120983/report-of-oozie-jobs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@YoungHobbit was right to point at [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120983/report-of-oozie-jobs) which is very similar to this one; his answer was dead on target when it comes to *extracting the entire list of jobs that have run on a specific day* with the *Oozie CLI* (command-line interface).
Just don't forget to specify an "unbounded" reply e.g. `-len 999999999` to avoid side effects (defaut is to show only the first 100 matches, which may be way too low if you run a lot of frequent jobs).

The trick is that you can make a more complex filter such as 
  `"startCreatedTime=2016-06-28T00:00Z;endcreatedtime=2016-06-28T10:00Z;status=FAILED"`
... but you cannot request jobs that have FAILED ***or*** have been KILLED ***or*** have been SUSPENDED *(which may result from a temporary YARN or HDFS outage)* ***or*** are still suspiciously RUNNING *(because a sub-workflow is SUSPENDED for instance)*.
So your best choice is to get the whole list, then filter out all jobs that have SUCCEEDED, with a plain old `grep` -- as suggested in another answer.

Then you will also need a complex `sed` or `awk` script to break down the ugly CLI output into a well-formed CSV. Ouch!

---

Now, you have an alternative to the Oozie CLI: the **Oozie REST API** (old Cloudera tutorial [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/06/how-to-use-the-apache-oozie-rest-api/), reference for Oozie V4.2 [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WebServicesAPI.html#Jobs_Information)) lets you query the Oozie server with **any programming language** that provides...

- an HTTP client
- and a way to parse JSON messages (using plain old regular expressions, if nothing else is available)

The logic would be basically the same -- fetch the list of all jobs in the desired time window, ignore SUCCEEDED jobs, parse the others to generate a CSV record, dump into a CSV file.
But your program would be more robust, since it would be based on *structured* JSON input.

One more thing: if you are familiar with Microsoft VBA, **you can even use an Excel macro to build the report dynamically**, in a self-service way. No need to bother with in intermediate CSV file.